# Facebook app: how to publish wallpost

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I havent use FBML and PHP SDK for a while and i just can get wallpost work anymore? Last year my code works for fine but now it wont work... so how my app can wallpost again? Help :)

Old code:

```
    <?php

  require_once('fb/src/facebook.php');

  $config = array(
    'appId' => '******',
    'secret' => '***********',
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();



$tiedosto = file("http://mydomain.com/doh.txt");

$sids = $tiedosto[$total];

$tiditii = "What's here:";
$message = "";
$text = "Checkout!";

 $attachment = array('name' => "$tiditii", 'href' => 'http://mydomain.com/do',
 'description' => "$sids
  ", 'media' => array(array('type' => 'image', 'src' => 'http://mydomain.com/pic.gif',
 'href' => 'http://mydomain.com/do')));
?>
<script>
function callback_function(){document.setLocation("http://apps.facebook.com/myapp");};
function publishPost() {
        var msg = <?= json_encode($message) ?>;
        var attachment = <?= json_encode($attachment) ?>;
        Facebook.streamPublish(msg, attachment);
}
</script><p>
<input name="Next" type="button" id="button" class="appMY_APP_ID_button" value="Publish" onclick="publishPost(); return false;"/>
```

Comment: what response do you get? How do you know it's not working? Nothing happens? Error message?

Comment: I get error message: Error while loading page from myapp
Empty response received.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this using the graph API

```
   $attachment =  array(
            'access_token' => $access_token,
            'message' => "Hello, here is a post",
            'name' => "",
            'link' => "http://www......",
            'description' => "Write here your description",
            'picture'=> "http://www.yourserver.com/images/test.jpg";
            );
        //print_r($attachment);
        $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $attachment);
```

Facebook PHP SDK can be found [here](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about php.. but why don't you use FB's java script sdk. It's easy to use.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Comment: Can you show me some simple example how to publish something in wall by using javascript? And what that "channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File" means. Do i need to put some file to my server?

Comment: Channel file addresses some issues with cross domain browsers. You don't need to put anything on server. To publish something on facebook wall you will need to have a cross domain reciever xd_reciever.htm file at your root. Once you initialize the java script SDK you can call any api from there. To post on facebook profile you can find it at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/ . to load the javascript sdk see "Loading" section at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/